# Printing a random string from an array

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String word;
String[] RobinWords = {"Hole In A Donut", "Bankruptcy", "Popcorn", "Ravioli", "Hijack", "Camouflage", "Key Hole", "New Year's Eve", "Trampoline", "Zorro", "Hallucination", "Alter Ego", "Backfire", "Batman"};

Random rand = new Random();


word = RobinWords [rand.nextInt(RobinWords.length)];


System.out.println("Holy " + word + ", Batman!");
System.out.println("Holy " + word + ", Batman!");
System.out.println("Holy " + word + ", Batman!");
System.out.println("Holy " + word + ", Batman!");
System.out.println("Holy " + word + ", Batman!");

}
```

It might seem a little silly but I couldn't figure out how to make the output to be different from one another.

Comment: replace any occurrence of `word` in the printing statements with: `RobinWords [rand.nextInt(RobinWords.length)]`, no?

Comment: You print the same string 5 times and it outputs the same string 5 times? Looks right to me!

Comment: The variable `word` holds a value and that's being used for the `println` statements. If you want each one to be different, replace `word` in the `println` statements with `RobinWords[rand.nextInt(RobinWords.length)]`

Comment: RobinWords is String array but you are using rand.nextInt(RobinWords.length)..

Answer (score 1):

What you likely meant to do

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
{
  word = RobinWords[rand.nextInt()]; 
  System.out.println("Holy " + word + ", Batman");
}
```

This code will select a randomized index, send it to your array, store that Index's corresponding element in a String then print the string.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a loop, and get a new random word on each iteration.

```
String[] robinWords = { "Hole In A Donut", "Bankruptcy", "Popcorn", "Ravioli", //
        "Hijack", "Camouflage", "Key Hole", "New Year's Eve", "Trampoline", //
        "Zorro", "Hallucination", "Alter Ego", "Backfire", "Batman" };

Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int index = rand.nextInt(robinWords.length);
    System.out.printf("Holy %s, Batman!%n", robinWords[index]);
}
```

Note that I have tried to improve the readability of your code by using a more standard name for `robinWords` and using `printf` instead of `String` concatenation. If you need five unique phrases, then you should probably prefer a `Set`; and assuming you're using Java 8+, you could do something like

```
Set<String> wordSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Random rand = new Random();
while (wordSet.size() < 5) {
    int index = rand.nextInt(robinWords.length);
    wordSet.add(robinWords[index]);
}
wordSet.stream().forEachOrdered(word -> 
        System.out.printf("Holy %s, Batman!%n", word));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
System.out.println("Holy " +  RobinWords [rand.nextInt(RobinWords.length)] + ", Batman!");
```

Because when `rand.nextInt()` execute it only generate random number once